# Python code doesn't work as expected?

Tags: python

The expected behaviour for this is to print `2949 is the magic number!` when it hits 2949, yet the loop doesn't. The loop seems to start at 19, then jump to 513920 - why is this?

```
magicNumber = 2949

for x in range(0, 100000000):
    if (x is magicNumber):
        print(x, "is the magic number!")
```

Comment: Try `if x == magicNumber:`

Comment: try == instead of 'is'

Comment: The operator `is` tests object identity, not value identity.